# LINQ passthrough provider?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, custom-linq-providers

I've implemented simple `IQueryable` and `IQueryProvider` classes that collect statistical data on LINQ expression trees.  This part works fine.  Next, I would like to pass the expression tree off to the default LINQ-to-Objects provider for evaluation, since I don't need to execute it any differently.  In order words, I'd like my provider to collect stats as a side-effect, passing the query on to the default LINQ implementation.

However, I am having difficulty getting a handle to the default provider.  I thought that I could simply save a reference to the original `IEnumerable` collection and then return the default provider (from my custom `IQueryable`) like:

```
IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
{
    get { return _my_provider.OriginalIEnum().AsQueryable().Provider; }
}
```

but this does not work correctly.  The code eventually throws a `StackOverflowException`.  What I *think* is happening (gleaned from single-stepping in debug mode) is that the LINQ runtime fetches the provider from the above method, then it fetches the expression tree from my custom `IQueryable`, and then it notices that the top-level expression is my custom `IQueryable`.  So it starts the process over again, trying to find the appropriate provider.  It does this endlessly until a stack overflow occurs.

Right now, the only thing I can think of is to come up with another visitor which produces another expression tree with the custom `IQueryable` nodes removed so that the LINQ runtime will call the default provider.  That's a fair amount of work, since I need to visit every leaf to ensure that there are no nested `Call` expressions which call my custom `IQueryable` again.  Is there a simpler approach?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So do you have some recursion going on where the provider is getting itself?

Comment: Exactly.  Which is puzzling, because I believe that I ought to be getting a reference to the original provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the real issue here is exactly the one described in [Pass LINQ expression to another QueryProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704027/pass-linq-expression-to-another-queryprovider).